# Good solution to fetch data from firebase based on uid cross the randomKey

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't change the DB structure. I want to get all matches with a specific uid as the picture. I have no idea how to cross the randomKey. My solution is to add a uid at the top level of the node then compare with the uid under the randomKey.

[image]

Comment: The question states *I can't change the DB structure* but then says *add a uid at the top level of the node*. If you can't change the structure then you shouldn't be able to add a uid. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I can add but cannot change the existing. I would like to figure out the way to search existing structure because the adding will need more code tobe changed in the adding record. Sorry, i am making you a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, since you can 'add' but not 'change' your structure, is to 'add' a child node that represents all guessers uid's that guessed under that match node. The order or count doesn't matter since we just want to return the matches node (match_id_1, match_id_2 etc)

```
matches
   match_id_1
      TzEnmFC: true
      Tss9S9i: true
      T99a0ds: true
```

then perform a query on matches were that users uid = true

```
let queryRef = self.ref.child("matches")
let ref = queryRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "some_uid").queryEqual(toValue: true)
ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    //do something with query results
})
```

Comment: yes, this solution is what i am doing. i think that you all could have a way to fetch the data cross the random key.